# Camera that saves images directly on harddisk

Tags: image, camera

I have kind of special problem. I'm looking for a way a camera is saving the images directly on the hard disk of a computer/server when the picture is taken. Here's a little background:

I have a ERP software written with PHP. At the moment you can take pictures with a Logitech webcam which has a shutter release. Via the Logitech software you can set the path for the folder where the images are stored. The ERP software is then accessing those images.
The problem is that the webcam takes very crappy pictures and it isn't produced anymore.
I haven't found any digital camera that provides the same way to saves the pictures directly on the computer/server.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to create employee badge in your ERP. Unless you are using the camera API to control when a picture is taken, I am afraid you will have to copy from the SD card to the hard drive.

Comment: No, not employee badges but pictures of damages on products :) It's a kind of complaint management tool.
I thought so, that this will be not easy.  Thanks anyway.